# How does inheritance of Attributes work in MVC 5 when overriding a property?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, inheritance, attributes

I want to have certain virtual properties decorated in a base class, inherit from the base class, override the property and decorate with additional attributes (e.g. sometimes display name is different, or field is required), and have the attributes from the base class still apply.

Is this possible?

Here's an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
public class MySSN
{
    [InputMask("999-99-9999")] //NOT available in the list of attributes!
    [Display(Name = "Social Security Number")] //NOT available in the list of attributes!
    public virtual string TheSSN { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}

public class SocialSecurityNumber : MySSN
{
    [Required] //Available in the list of attributes!
    public override string TheSSN { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}

public class PersonModel
{
    //...
    public SocialSecurityNumber SSN { get; set; } = new SocialSecurityNumber();

    //...
}
```

EditorFor:

```
@model Models.PersonModel
@using MyHTMLExtensions

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        @Html.DLAPTextBoxFor(m => m.SSN.TheSSN, new { style = "max-width: 200px;" })
    </div>
</div>
```

InputMask Attribute:
NOTE: The OnMetadataCreated() fires properly when my custom control retrieves the metadata!  However, it is not the *full name* of the control.  It is only the underlying "TheSSN" name from the Inheriting class "SocialSecurityNumber()".  The crux of the problem is that I need the *full name* of the control to be used here, but I understand that because Metadata is fired before knowing anything about the model, that's not possible at this level.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = true, Inherited = true)]
public class InputMaskAttribute : Attribute, IMetadataAware
{
    private string _mask = string.Empty;
    private string _placeHolder = string.Empty;

    public InputMaskAttribute(string mask, string placeHolder = "")
    {
        _mask = mask;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(placeHolder))
        {
            _placeHolder = string.Format(",{{placeholder:\"{0}\"}}", placeHolder);
        }
    }

    public string Mask
    {
        get { return _mask; }
    }

    public string PlaceHolder
    {
        get { return _placeHolder; }
    }

    private const string ScriptText = "<script type='text/javascript'>" +
                                        "$(document).ready(function () {{" +
                                        "$('#{0}').mask('{1}'{2});}});</script>";


    public const string templateHint = "_mask";     // Causes _mask.cshtml to be used

    private int _count;

    //public string Id
    //{
    //    //get { return "PhoneNumber"; }
    //    get { return "maskedInput_" + _count; }
    //}

    internal HttpContextBase Context
    {
        get { return new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current); }
    }

    public void CreateMask(ModelMetadata metadata, string PropertyName)
    {
        string Id = PropertyName;
        string key = string.Format("InputMask_{0}", Id);
        if (!Context.Items.Contains(key))
        {
            //Only do this if the key is not already present
            var list = Context.Items["Scripts"] as IList<string> ?? new List<string>();
            _count = list.Count;
            metadata.TemplateHint = templateHint;
            metadata.AdditionalValues[templateHint] = Id;
            string scriptToAdd = string.Format(ScriptText, Id, Mask, PlaceHolder);
            list.Add(scriptToAdd);
            Context.Items["Scripts"] = list;
            Context.Items.Add(key, scriptToAdd);
        }
    }
    //USING the special TEXTBOXFOR to handle this in most cases.
    public void OnMetadataCreated(ModelMetadata metadata)
    {
        CreateMask(metadata, metadata.PropertyName);
    }
}
```

In the HTMLExtensions class, my custom Text Box:
I can work around the problem of the OnMetadataCreated not giving me the full name by checking for the custom attribute, and creating a second jQuery script with the full name of the control here.  However, that only works when the InputAttribute is decorating the Inheriting member's override.  In other words, I cannot read the *base* member's attributes here (SocialSecurityNumber.MySSN.TheSSN - "[InputMask]" and "[Display]" attributes), only the *inheriting* member's attributes (SocialSecurityNumber.TheSSN - "[Required]" attribute).

I know the *base* attributes are taking effect because the display name is displayed properly, and when getting the metadata, the "OnMetadataCreated()" is firing properly (just the wrong name).  Thus, the attributes are properly inherited!

So where are they in the list of attributes???

```
namespace MyHTMLExtensions
{
public static class HtmlExtensions
{
    internal static MvcHtmlString DLAPTextBoxFor<TModel, TValue>(
        this HtmlHelper<TModel> html,
        Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression,
        IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes = null,
        bool readOnly = false)
    {
        if (htmlAttributes == null)
        {
            htmlAttributes = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        }

        ModelMetadata modelMetadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, html.ViewData);

        //Check for special InputMaskAttribute
        //ONLY FINDS THE "[Required]" ATTRIBUTE, BUT  NOT THE BASE ATTRIBUTES.  HOW DO I GET THE BASE ATTRIBUTES THAT ARE INHERITED???  I know they are inherited properly because the Display value shows properly on the page!
        InputMaskAttribute testAtt = GetModelAttribute<InputMaskAttribute>(modelMetadata, false);
        if (testAtt != null)
        {
            //Get the FULL ID of the control (might be nested) to use in the jQuery that will create for the control
            string fullControlID = html.IdFor(expression).ToString();
            testAtt.CreateMask(modelMetadata, fullControlID);
        }
    //........
    }

    internal static TAttribute GetModelAttribute<TAttribute>(ModelMetadata modelMetadata, bool inherit) where TAttribute : Attribute
    {
        if (modelMetadata == null) throw new ArgumentException("modelMetadata");
        var containerType = modelMetadata.ContainerType;

        TAttribute attribute = null;
        if (containerType != null)
        {
            //When overriding a base class property decorated with attributes, the base attributes are not in the list - only the overriding property attributes are listed.
            //object[] allAttributes = containerType.GetProperty(modelMetadata.PropertyName).GetCustomAttributes(inherit);
            TAttribute[] attributes = ((TAttribute[])
                containerType.GetProperty(modelMetadata.PropertyName).GetCustomAttributes(typeof(TAttribute), inherit));

            attribute = attributes.FirstOrDefault();
        }

        return attribute;
    }
}
```

When calling GetModelAttribute(), the base class attributes are not available in the list, but all of the attributes actually take effect. Because the crux of the problem is that I need the full name of the control to properly create the Input Mask, I need to have all the custom attribute available (all the way back the base model) in the list of attributes.

If I move the attribute out of the base class, and into the inheriting class, I can properly read that attribute's existence!

How do I get the base attributes to display in the list of attributes????